# Socket, accept() function, Invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am getting an error "Invalid argument" when i call the accept() function on the server side of a client-server application. I don't get what is wrong and if you see what is wrong let me know please. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, len;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    if(argc < 2){
        perror("Add more arguments");
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        perror("Error at socket()");    
    }
    printf("Socketfd: %d\n",sockfd);
    bzero((char *)&server, sizeof(server));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    server.sin_family = AF_UNIX;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if(bind (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) <0){
        perror("Error at bind ()-server");  
    }

    listen(sockfd,5);

    int readval;
    char buffer[256];
    for(;;){
        len = sizeof(client);
        newsockfd = accept (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server,&len);
        if (newsockfd == -1){
            perror("Erroare at accept()");      
        }
        else do{        
            readval = (sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
            if (readval < 0 ){
                perror("Error at reading()");       
            }
            else if (readval == 0){
                printf("End conection");            
            }
            else{
                printf("Mesage is: %s\n", buffer);
            }
        }while (readval > 0);
        close(newsockfd);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You set `len` to `sizeof(client)` but pass in `&server`?  (I don't think that's your problem, but it can't be right).

Comment: Something is missing here: `readval = (sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));`

Comment: Also you need to check the return value of `listen()`.

Comment: Why casting `&server` to `struct sockaddr*` when it's already of that type???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `sockaddr_un` instead of `sockaddr_in` for Unix domain sockets OR substitute `AF_UNIX` with `AF_INET`.

Plus, check the return of listen.

Plus change this line

```
readval = (sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

with

```
readval = read(newsockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

because data is going to be sent through the newly created socket and not on the listening one

Plus, as mentioned by @trojanfoe, subst the `server` with the `client` structure into the `accept()` call

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
newsockfd = accept (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, &len);
```

Should be:

```
newsockfd = accept (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);
```

From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept):

> The argument addr is a pointer to a sockaddr structure. This structure
>   is filled in with the address of the peer socket, as known to the
>   communications layer. The exact format of the address returned addr is
>   determined by the socket's address family (see socket(2) and the
>   respective protocol man pages). When addr is NULL, nothing is filled
>   in; in this case, addrlen is not used, and should also be NULL.

Also check the return value from `listen()`.

Comment: Ok, so my sock id is 3. I checked the return value of listen and it was -1(so i'm getting an error there too). Additionally, after these changes i'm getting an error at bind too("Address already in use").

Comment: OK, that error is pretty common with `listen` and you need to `setsockopt()` `SO_REUSEADDR` so that the port can be reused.  The `listen()` is the root cause of your issue, not the wrong address being passed to `accept()` as stated in my answer (that will only cause a minor error).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue before and it was due to not having the read function in a loop. Here is an example I did before.

```
while (1) {
        new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr,
                 &sin_size);
        if (new_sockfd == -1)
            perror("accepting connection");
        printf("server: got connection from %s port %d\n",
            inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),
            ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
        recv_length = recv(new_sockfd, &buffer, DATA, 0);

        while (recv_length > 0) {
            printf("RECV: %d bytes\n", recv_length);
            dump(buffer, recv_length);
            recv_length = recv(new_sockfd, &buffer, DATA, 0);
        }

        close(new_sockfd);
    }
```